# Как погасить/выключить дисплей через ADB?

Tags: android, adb, android-adb

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо средствами ADB погасить дисплей Android устройства. Не важно как (смена яркости в 0, отключение подачи питания на экран), главное чтобы OS считала что дисплей включен. Смартфон используется в качестве тестового мини сервера с разбитым сенсором, при выключении экрана через Power понижается частота работы процессора, в следствии чего, снижается производительность в целом. Да и некоторые приложения просто не могу корректно работать в режиме сна. Смарт управляется через ADB удалённо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте проэмулировать нажатие клавиши питания - [KEYCODE_POWER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_POWER):

```
adb shell input keyevent 26
```

Comment: а не лучше вместо 26 указать POWER? Так проще запомнить + не факт что везде этот код отвечает за POWER

Comment: @Flippy 1) не уверен, что `keyevent POWER` работает
2) `KEYCODE_POWER` всегда равен `26` - это как раз захардкожено в недрах оси

Comment: 1) Работает, проверил 2) Спасибо, не знал, что в любом андроиде одинаковый. А как насчет кастом прошивок